# command not found error on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, google-app-engine, terminal

When I do `ls` , my command is listed. So it means I'm on correct path.
But when i try to execute i get error `dev_appserver.sh: command not found`
(I'm quite new to Mac OS terminal.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, check `dev_appserver.sh` permissions, then try executing like `./dev_appserver.sh`

Answer (score 0):

// ===== Solution for macOS Catalina 10.15.7 =====

1. Locate directory of vue at `/Users/[username]/.npm-global/bin`
2. Open bash profile `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`
3. Add `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/[username]/.npm-global/bin`
4. Exit (control + x) > Save (Y) > Enter (return) > Restart Terminal

// ========== Worked For Me ==========